# Excel VBA Insert Rows above Cells with specific Formatting

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am not very good in VBA but I already looked for an answer online for hours. Hope you can help me.

I would like to insert rows above cells that are filled with a specific color (two different color indexes). Is this actually possible? I only have text in column A.
So I would need a  kind of formula, like "if one cell in column A is black or grey (colorindex 1 and ?), insert one blank, white row above.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub RowYourBoat()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set r3 = Nothing

    For Each r2 In r1
        If r2.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            If r3 Is Nothing Then
                Set r3 = r2
            Else
                Set r3 = Union(r3, r2)
            End If
        End If
    Next r2

    If r3 Is Nothing Then
    Else
        r3.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

This is for black, the *ColorIndex* for grey depends on what shade of grey you use.